# Terraform iteration count

Tags: foreach, terraform

how do I make Terraform increment a variable by 1 for each iteration in a for_each loop??

```
locals {
 
 inbound_mgmt = {
  
  ## List of Locations/sites needing to access the management interface
    "HQ" = {ip = "1.2.3.4/24"},
    "SITE1" = {ip = "3.4.5.6/29"},
    "SITE2" = {ip = "6.7.8.9/29"}
   }
}
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "allow_inbound_mgmt" {
  for_each = local.inbound_mgmt
  name                        = "Allowmgmt-${each.key}"
  priority                    =  1000
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
```

I want to AUTOMATICLY increment the priority by 1 for each iteration, starting at 1000 for the first var entry.
I do NOT want to set the priority as a part of each entry in the variable

I have tried all kinds of examples with both for_each anc count, but I can't crack it...

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You could however add an additional key to the local variable which will be its priority and then reference it in the `priority` argument.

Comment: As far as I know this would only be possible if `inbound_mgmt` is a `list` or `set` type.

Answer (score 0):

Instances declared using `for_each` are not in any particular order, so there is no automatic way to assign incrementing indices to them.

If you need incrementing integers associated with your objects you will need to build those into the data structure you pass to `for_each`, either by hard-coding them when you write the data structure (e.g. directly into your `inbound_mgmt` data structure) or by deriving a new data structure that includes incrementing integers in some order decided by your configuration.

For example, if you want to assign the integers using alphabetical (really: lexical by character code) order then you could do so like this:

```
locals {
  inbound_mgmt_with_idx = tomap({
    for i, k in sort(keys(local.inbound_mgmt)) : k => {
      ip    = local.inbound_mgmt[k].ip
      index = 1000 + i
    }
  })
}
```

The `sort` function returns a list, so in this `for` expression the local symbol `i` is the index into that list of the current element.

If you need to explicitly define the order rather than just relying on an automatic sort then you'll need to instead write your original value as a list, so that the order of elements in that list will be the order of the assigned integers:

```
locals {

 inbound_mgmt = tolist([
   {
     name = "HQ"
     ip   = "1.2.3.4/24"
   },
   {
     name = "SITE1"
     ip   = "3.4.5.6/29"
   },
   {
     name = "SITE2"
     ip   = "6.7.8.9/29"
   },
 ])
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "allow_inbound_mgmt" {
  for_each = tomap({
    for i, r in local.inbound_mgmt : r.name => {
      ip    = r.ip
      index = 1000 + i
    }
  })

  # ...
}
```

In this case the order of the elements in `local.inbound_mgmt` (which is now a list) will be the order in which the integers get assigned. You can use `each.value.index` inside the resource block to access the index of the current instance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input, I made it work using count in stead of for_each

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "allow_inbound_mgmt" {
  count                       = length(var.inbound_mgmt)
  name                        = "AllowMGMT-${keys(var.inbound_mgmt)[count.index]}"
  priority                    =  1000 + tonumber("${count.index}")
  source_address_prefix       = "${values(var.inbound_mgmt)[count.index]["ip"]}"
```